# lag function in Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark 2.3 Structured streaming and trying to use 'lag' function. However looks like lag is not supported in structured streaming.

```
val output = spark.sql("SELECT temperature, time, lag(temperature, 1) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS PrevTemp FROM InputTable")
```

Get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets; line 1 pos 0;
```

Is there an alternate way to achieve this 'lag' functionality with structured streaming?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't.

Probably, you may play with mapGroupsWithState. for example:

```
    case class PayLoad(event_time: java.sql.Timestamp, data: String)

def mappingFunction(key: java.sql.Timestamp, values: Iterator[PayLoad], state: GroupState[PayLoad]): PayLoad = {
  ??? // Work with values iterator
}

val temperature: DataFrame = ???
temperature
  .withColumn("event_time", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.current_timestamp())
  .as[PayLoad]
  .groupByKey(_.event_time)
  .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(mappingFunction)
```

You don't need to keep state, but in this way you have access to values iterator and you are able to solve any task.

Keep in mind, that in this case all micro batch data will go to one partition and with huge payload may lead to huge latencies or even OOM. (as well as with `OVER (ORDER BY time)`)

Hope it helps.